# How do I create custom URLs/paths?

Tags: services, uri

I have been playing with the [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module for a couple of days. According to general REST API best practices, the GET URL paths I should use are:

```
/buildings
/buildings/4
/buildings/4/rooms
/buildings/4/rooms/5
```

..where in my Drupal site 'Building' and 'room' are both content types, and '4' and '5', the node-ids.

Using the [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module, I can create the following calls:

```
/node/type=building
/node/4
```

And with the Services Views module, I can customize the path a little more:

```
/buildings
```

But the only way to get a specific building is by:

```
/buildings?nid=4
```

In order to enable the call path `/buildings/4` do I have to create a custom Services resource?